# Proper way to implement Queue with MFC?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc

**What I want to do is;** Store some string values in a text file in multi threaded environment.
Then I store each and every string values in a Queue and then read that queue step by step and write that values into text file.

I saw some example in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tze823w7.aspx) about **Queues**. From that example I made some changes and created this code segment to store `CString` values.But I can't achieve it from this code.

```
class CQueue :public CTypedPtrList < CObList, CString* >
{
public:
    void AddToEnd(CString* newLog) {
        AddTail(newLog);
    }
    CString* GetFromFront() {
        return IsEmpty() ? NULL : RemoveHead();
    }
};
```

**Then I try to call like this:**

```
CQueue q;
CString str("data1");
q.AddToEnd(&str);
```

*It's give this error:*

```
'void CObList::AddTail(CObList *)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t>>> ' to 'CObject *'
```

What is the best way to implement Queue in MFC ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CString is no object or better: it isn't derived from CObject. But you said the the list should be derived from CObList. You have to use CPtrList instead.

```
class CQueue :public CTypedPtrList < CPtrList, CString* >
```

Please note: But even than you code is very dangerous. In your sample you create a pointer to a variable that exists on the stack. If the function exists the pointer gets invalid...

Comment: Now I have another issue while getting CString* type integer. As an example if we store 124; it will print only 1 other 2,4 numbers are missing. ?

Comment: This is a new question... may be you are outputting just a character,

Comment: Yes this is new question.. I used ** (pointer of pointer) to get value

Comment: You should open a new one. Using ** will always only return the first character. Please learn C++ basics.